# Problem - Sum of digit of $n$ and $n^2$

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

How can i prove that : 
There are infinitely many natural numbers $m \geq 0$ with sum of digits of $(m) = n$ and sum of digits of $(m^2) = $$($sum of digits of $(m))^2$ ?

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$11, 101, 1001,\ldots$$

Comment: Another hint, 1, 11, 1011, 10001011, ...